# Can not find class implementing interface at an open-source project hosted at GitHub

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to figure out at where a Java class implements an interface at an open-source project hosted at GitHub. It is the following function:

https://github.com/ontop/ontop/blob/version4/core/model/src/main/java/it/unibz/inf/ontop/injection/IntermediateQueryFactory.java#L48

I have tried so far to figure out of how Google Guice works, searching for the call history, using Eclipse, and searching for the function by its name. I am still unable to find any Java class implementing that interface.

Answer (score 0):

The interface your'e mentioning is an [assisted factory](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) in Guice. It is used to create instances of a certain type with arguments **you** specify and bindings that are specified in the Guice injector itself. The interface will be implemented at runtime by Guice. You can find out more in the official [Guice Wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject)